# Can you convert two fisheyes images into a single equirectangular image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two fisheyes images from a 360 camera:

[image]

And I'd like to convert them into a single equirectangular image like this using OpenCV. Is this possible?

[image]